Are buildings out of salt feasible?
I understand that salt is very susceptible for erosion, but a castle made out of salt or maybe walls seems like an interesting idea. Is there any historical evidence of something like this happening? Or if not, how could something similar happen?

Yes, buildings have been made out of salt. On the other hand, this site is not a free-of-charge research service.

Portland Cement is technically salt
In Chemistry a salt is any ionic compound, Portland Cement is primarily Limestone which is Calcium Oxide (a salt). As this is the principal ingredient in most concrete (which is an aggregate of many materials) it wouldn't be wrong to say that most modern buildings are made of salt, as most buildings have a large amount of concrete components, especially for the foundation.

I disagree with this because the cement in concrete polymerizes.

@GaultDrakkor Are you saying that the Calcium Oxide in cement forms a polymer? I'd be interested to see your source on that assertion.

I can't find what i recall reading about several years ago. Search has too many references to adding carbon based polymers to concrete. A weak argument is if hydraulic cement's chemistry portion. is considered, many reactions occur. creating minerals that have many repeating units, If you squint at it and bend some definitions its a polymer as opposed to just crystals.

Sort of
The issue is water. If there isn't water, then salt is fine.
As for examples, lots of stuff has been created inside salt mines in Europe

Wieliczka salt mine chapel, Poland

Sure, absolutely.
Provided that your buildings sit in the middle of a desert, never experience rainfall, and that all the household water is routed through standard clay/stone pipes and never touches salt.
Salty walls might also cause the erosion of the humans living in them, because being subjected to salt particles all the time dries your skin, mucus membranes and eyes.
the obvious problem is getting enough salt to build out of it. Even the greatest saltmines,saltpans and saltbeds provide barely enough material to do that in reasonable time, and you would have to transport the salt even further away from them towards even drier places.
Aside from pure salt bricks (which would be hard to make), there is one cool option to use salt for in construction. Salt lowers the melting point of clay. If you make a clay brick, coat it in salt, and then fire it, the salt on the surface will melt in one with the clay, forming Glaze. Salt glaze is almost glass-smooth can range in color from brown to stark blue, is waterproof, much harder than regular bricks, and quite beautiful. It also allows you to paint bricks (using differently colored glaze, or paint under the glaze) to create art.
So even if a salt castle idea fails, you can have a castle made of salt-glazed bricks, which would look like a work of art, gleam in the sun, shed water and last for millennia.

You might be able to make buildings mostly of salt, but not entirely of salt.
As has been mentioned in other answers, salt is very susceptible to damage by water, and so it must be shielded from water. Furthermore, as mentioned by Going Durden, salt isn't the best for people's health, so humans have to be shielded from the salt as well.
My proposition: salt infill walls:

Rubble infill is a technique that was used by the Ancient Egyptians, Greeks, and Romans. It continued to be used in the Middle Ages.
I would suggest you replace the rubble in the diagram with salt, and use more conventional stone or clay bricks for the outer wall. If you formed the salt into blocks, you could maybe reduce the thickness of the outer bricks, but I'm also not an engineer, so take it with a grain of salt (pun semi-intended).

The problem with salt-fill construction is that in anything but an extreme desert, it tends to cause the stones to break down through salt weathering.

@Mark Maybe; I'm not the most knowledgeable about salt's properties. However, I think that salt-fill would be the most viable above-ground construction technique that uses salt.
